# AzureReader2 not working with querystring

Tags: imageresizer

I have images in private blockblobs in Azure.

I am using Azure Reader 2 and can access the image like this http://localhost:55328/azure/00001/IMG_0001.JPG - it works fine and redirects to the blob with a Shared Access Signature.

However, if I try to resize the image, e.g. IMG_0001.JPG?width=100&height=100, I just get a 404.

Stepping through the code, I notice this line

```
if (e.VirtualPath.StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && e.QueryString.Count == 0)
        {
         ....
        }
```

So, if there's a QueryString, no processing happens.

Debug output here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/28fd112eec194181baae

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your debugging misled you. It's true that redirection only happens when there is no querystring. When there *are* parameters, the blob needs to be modified, which means we *must* proxy it. A 302 redirect in that scenario is impossible.

AzureReader registers a IVirtualImageProvider, which ImageResizer automatically uses when handling all the proxying, processing, and caching.

**The default behavior is to download, modify, and re-serve the data. The 302 redirect is just an optimization for throughput on unmodified files.**

Notes:

sharedAccessExpiryTime is ignored, there is no setting by that name.

If you are going to reference code, it's best to [link to the line in the file on github](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/d66072a13d61421d357a66d0d349b84be9b1c804/Plugins/AzureReader2/AzureReader.cs#L106), otherwise we can't easily find the context. Press y on any github page to get a permalink, then click a line number (or range).

Comment: Thank-you for your answer Nathanael. So, am I doing something wrong when trying to resize using the AzureReader? Should I be passing http://localhost:55328/azure/00001/IMG_0001.JPG to another plugin for resizing?

Comment: No,  IMG_0001.JPG?width=100&height=100 should work. It's likely that something is preventing VirtualPathProviders from working. Or, perhaps StaticFileModule is not even installed?

Comment: This is a pretty out of the box project in VS2013, so I'm struggling to see what I'm doing wrong. I've not had to manually configure StaticFileModule previously (I admin, I've not used AzureReader2 either). Is that something I should be setting up?

Comment: It's something people often forget to install when setting up IIS. If it's out of the box, maybe you could zip it up and upload it somewhere so I can try to repo the problem?

Comment: It's Kendo UI that's breaking it. Dammit! I'm never sure whether using Telerik saves me or costs me time!