# ImageResizer with AzureReader2 returns 404 for all requests

Tags: umbraco, imageresizer

I'm having a hard time getting the **AzureReader2** plugin for ImageResizer to work. Basically, all requests yield **404**'s.

Here is a summary of the situation:

- **ImageResizer 3** (unable to upgrade to 4 because of Newtonsoft dependency clashing with Umbraco 7)
- **/resizer.debug** works fine and doesn't report any errors
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration 2.0.0.0
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 4.3.0.0

Requesting the blob directly works fine, with a URL like:

http://ACCOUNTNAME.blob.core.windows.net/media/1004/some-image.jpg

However, the following URL does *not* work:

http://localhost/azure/media/1004/some-image.jpg

Appending a query string with ImageResizer commands yields the same result.

Here is the config:

```
<resizer>
   <diagnostics enableFor="Localhost" />
   <plugins>
     <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
     <add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/azure/" endpoint="http://ACCOUNTNAME.blob.core.windows.net/" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=ACCOUNTNAME;AccountKey=ACCOUNTKEY" />
     <add name="DiskCache" />
   </plugins>
   <diskcache dir="~/App_Data/imageresizer" />
</resizer>
```

I'm a bit lost, any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit:** As per Nathanael's suggestion I built ImageResizer 4 with Newtonsoft 6, and placed the following assemblies in the bin folder:

- ImageResizer.dll
- ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.dll
- ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.dll
- ImageResizer.Storage.dll

I also removed the "MvcRoutingShim" plugin from config, as it is installed by default.

Now everything works as expected with ImageResizer 4 on an Umbraco 7 site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to use an assembly binding redirect on Newtonsoft.Json so that you can upgrade to ImageResizer 4. Azure makes breaking changes to their APIs frequently, and ImageResizer 3 no longer tracks those changes.

ImageResizer 4 can also work with an older version of Newtonsoft if you are comfortable downloading and rebuilding ImageResizer from source.

Older versions of ImageResizer also (incorrectly) return a 404 for any FileNotFoundException... which can occur if assemblies (like the azure SDK) are missing.

Precompilation will also break azurereader2..

Related:
[Resizing an image using AzureReader2 results in 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685102/resizing-an-image-using-azurereader2-results-in-404/17757524#17757524)

[AzureReader2 not working with querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590779/azurereader2-not-working-with-querystring)

If none of the above suggestions work, I would suggest stepping through the source with a debugger to discover why image providers do not work. First upgrade to v4 if at all possible.

Comment: Building the source for ImageResizer 4 with Newtonsoft 6 solved everything. Thanks again, Nat!